# DBUnit changes not visible inside transactional Spring test

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, transactional, dbunit

I try to fill a Database Table with DBUnit within a Spring Transactional Test.
The datasource is a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy. So i would thing giving this source to DBUnit and than filling the Table should be visible for the jdbcTemplate query afterwards?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"many contexts"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
@Transactional
public class DBTest {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void setJdbcTemplate(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired(required = true)
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void test() throws Exception {
        IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSource);
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConn, new XmlDataSet(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("TABLE.xml")));

        System.out.println("Es wurden gefunden : " + this.jdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select count(*) from TABLE"));
        System.out.println("blaaa");

    }
```

The query always returns 0.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of solution....
I changed DBUnit version from 2.4.9 to 2.5.2 now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when dbUnit and the production app share the same transaction/datasource.  What "fixes" it is a "flush", either by manually invoking a flush in the test or using a separate transaction or db connection (so dbUnit's changes flush).

Comment: i tried sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); after the clean insert. No difference :(